# Is it possible to override the auto-indentation of comments in VB.NET/VS2008?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, comments

Is it possible to override the auto-indentation of comments in VB.NET (Using visual studio 2008)?

Please see the comment above the second Case Statement in the code below for context.

The IDE auto-indents the comment beyond the following Case Statement. I would like to override this behavior and bring it in line with the C in Case that follows.

```
Select Case E.Type

    'General Events
    Case EventType.General_StartServer
        'Initialize the Server Brain (ME)
        GLOBAL__I_AM_THE_SERVER = True
        Init()

        'Server Alerts
    Case EventType.ServerAlert_Chat
        EventManager.SendEventToAllClients(New GameEvent(EventType.ClientAlert_Chat, 0, 0, 0, E.Str))

End Select
```

Comment: This remains extremely annoying multiple versions of VS later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can completely turn off the reformatting, I bet that isn't the solution you had in mind.

Personally, in the given code, I put my comments pertaining to the case underneath it.

```
Select Case E.Type
    Case EventType.General_StartServer
        ' The server has started, so we need to do blah.

    Case EventType.ServerAlert_Chat
        ' A chat has sent a server alert, so do blah.
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this in the menu:

> Tools->Options->Text Editor->Basic->VB
>   Specific->Pretty listing
>   (reformatting) of code

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0y5th94.aspx):

> **Pretty Listing (reformatting) of code**
>
> The text editor reformats your code as
>   appropriate. When this option is
>   selected, the code editor will:
>
> - Align your code to the correct tab position

Comment: I'm happy with where it places the code, just not a few of the comments. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Other than adapting to put the comments after the case statement like @Jason suggests, I think so. Alternatively, tools like Resharper will allow you to customize a lot of those reformatting options very granularly and might work for you.